# From database to datetime picker

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a form with few datetime pickers, to be exact two pairs of dates and times.

[image]

Data from those pickers is combined and saved to database as DateTime in format

```
 16/05/2012 11:28:00 a.m.
```

Now, what I want to do is get value from database and put it into datetime pickers.

I've tried something like

```
string plannedDate =(dbFunctions.SQLReadColumn("task", "PlannedDate", TaskID));
        DateTime pDate = new DateTime(plannedDate.Substring(0,9);
        dtpDatePicker.Value=pDate;
```

where plannedDate contains string data in format as mentioned above, but I can't convert it to DateTime (second line incorrect). Is there an easy way to do it or do I have to cut the string into pieces for year, month etc?

Comment: is this winforms? also, you might want to fix your accepted rate.

Comment: I've fixed it with  

     dtpDatePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(plannedDate.Substring(0, 10));
            dtPDateTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(plannedDate.Substring(10, 6));

Answer (score 5):

Do like this

```
dtpDatePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(plannedDate.Substring(0, 10));
```

Similarly for Time

```
mytimepicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(plannedDate.Substring(10, 6));
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the [DateTime.TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1) in situations you may receive an invalid string as an input but don't want a exception to be throw:

```
DateTime dateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
{
    // Conversion succedded
}
else
{
    // Conversion failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime( gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "CDATE").ToString());
```